# Mask input on MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So, I'm trying to put some mask on my input, I have seen a lot of information arround this, however I couldn't find a way to work on my code. I tried with Jquery plugin **masked input** and **Inputmask**, any good results.

Here is my JS code with a function for each of those inputs:

```
(document).ready(function () {
     $("#telephone").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "(99) 9999-99999" });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

and the page where my input is:

```
<p>phone: <input type="text" id="phone" /></p>
<p>phone: <input type="text" id="telephone" /></p>
```

and on my _layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/maskedinput")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
```

absoluty nothing happens on my front.

I'm a newbie at coding yet, and english is my second language, but I hope that this question is understandable.

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using Third Party Library, you might want to look into [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core) which is Free and Open Source.

Usage is quite simple -

```js
$(function() {
   $("#telephone").kendoMaskedTextBox({
      mask: "(999) 000-0000"
   });
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
<input id="telephone" value="555 123 4567" />
```

Here is the sample code at [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/).

Comment: Thank you, work just fine =). A bit frustrated not knowing what was going on before tho